# Unable to load specific dll for plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, mef

I'm currently using MEF to load plugins for one of my applications. I want to move these plugins outside of the bin directory to a separate plugins directory so other applications can use the plugins. A problem that I'm running into is that one of the plugins is dependent on a custom xml serializing class in a separate dll and when I try to use the particular plugin, I get a "Could not load file or assembly" error when it tries to load the separate dll.

My app.config currently has the following:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="plugins"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I had to add probing in order of my original application to work with this particular dll. All plugin dlls were originally located in a subdirectory inside the bin called "plugins". But now that I want to move the plugins into a common directory for all applications, I would I go about fixing this issue? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would moving the custom xml serializing class/plugins to the GAC be a viable solution for you?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do that.

Comment: That is strange, I'm using MEF as well; I can put dependencies in the plugins directory and it just works. What catalog are you using? I imagine you should in any case be able to use ILMerge to join the dll's

Comment: post how you set your catalogs for your compositioncontainer please

Answer (score 0):

you have to ensure that all dependencies you need are in your catalogs.

at it have to look like something like that:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));//dependencies your plugin dll needs
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@"YourPluginFolderPath\Plugins\"));//your plugin dll's

 var cc = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
 var t = cc.GetExport<IMyPluginTestStuffExport>().Value;
```